# Magento 2 Get Core Config Data columns

Tags: magento2.2.2, core-config-data, scope, scopeinterface

How do one get the column `scope_id` from `core_config_data` via given path
E.G:

`$this->_config->getValue(self::MY_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)`;

The above returns the column `value` I need column `scope_id`

e.g: **getScopeID**

`$this->_config->getScopeID(self::MY_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)`